# Message queue passing old values C

Tags: c, process, message-queue

I am trying to develop a simple message queue in C but I am running towards some frustrating problems. I have a number of 10 processes that are divided in two groups of five. Each of the processes of this group must speak with only one of the processes of the other group, and to do that I have assigned different keys to the message queue creation (sorry if it is not the best idea but i'm new to C and trying to adapt). My main issue though is that when I run the code the first time if tells me that 'No such file or directory exists" as a mq error. When I run it from this point on the server receives the message just fine, but it receives the 'old' messages, which are the ones that the client has sent the prior execution. I've been trying to look for what to change but haven't come up with anything. This is my code:

**server.c**

```
int keys[] = {1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1115};


int msqid;
key_t keymq1;
struct msgbuf rcvbuffer;
keymq1 = keys[indiceProcesso];

if ((msqid = msgget(keymq1, 0666)) < 0)
    die("msgget()");


if (msgrcv(msqid, &rcvbuffer, MAXSIZE, 1, 0) < 0)
    die("msgrcv");

printf("Messaggio ricevuto da A con pid %d: %s\n",getpid(), rcvbuffer.mtext);
```

**client.c**

```
    int msqid1;
    int msgflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
    key_t keymq1;
    struct msgbuf sbuf;
    size_t buflen;
    keymq1 = keys[indiceProcesso];
    sbuf.mtype = 1;


    if ((msqid1 = msgget(keymq1, msgflg )) < 0)
        die("msgget");

    sbuf.mtype = 1;


    strcpy(sbuf.mtext,"My message");
    buflen = strlen(sbuf.mtext) + 1 ;

    if (msgsnd(msqid1, &sbuf, buflen, IPC_NOWAIT) < 0)
    {
        printf ("%d, %ld, %s, %zu\n", msqid1, sbuf.mtype, sbuf.mtext, buflen);
        die("msgsnd");
    }

    else 
        printf("Message Sent\n");
```

Hope you can help me out and thank you for your time.

Comment: Might need to use IPC_RMID with msgctl when done with a queue id?  See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgctl.2.html

Comment: I tried removing the queues manually but still nothing, it is fine when I use a normal key tough, but when I read from an array it just doesnt work well

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  it is missing a lot of necessary statements.

Comment: use `ftok()` to generate the keys, do not hard code them.

Comment: use `msgctl()` with `IPC_RMID` to remove any old instance of the message queue before creating a new message queue

Comment: What is the difference between hard coding a key and using ftok?